# Filtering data using And operator MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------+-----------+
| product_id | tag_id   | 
+-----------+-----------+
|         3 |    4      |
|         3 |   29      |
|        30 |   20      | 
|         3 |   19      | 
|        30 |   19      |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I want all product_ids which has tag_id in combination of 4 and 19 OR 4 and 25 OR 4 and 20. Result should come 3 but instead of that it comes 3 and 30 using below query :

```
select product_id 
from product_tag_mapping
where tag_id in ('4','19') or tag_id in (4,29) or tag_id in (4,20)
group by product_id
having count(distinct(tag_id)) >= 2
```

Can anyone help me what am I doing wrong ?

I tried other solution as well which gives me proper Result as product_id '3' but query is very big which is difficult for big size of database :

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id 
FROM product_tag_mapping AS t
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM product_tag_mapping AS t1
    WHERE t1.product_id = t.product_id
      AND t1.tag_id = 4
  )
AND EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM product_tag_mapping AS t2
    WHERE t2.product_id = t.product_id
      AND t2.tag_id = 19
  )
OR EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM product_tag_mapping AS t2
    WHERE t2.product_id = t.product_id
      AND t2.tag_id = 4
  )
  AND EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM product_tag_mapping AS t2
    WHERE t2.product_id = t.product_id
      AND t2.tag_id = 20
  )

   OR EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM product_tag_mapping AS t2
    WHERE t2.product_id = t.product_id
      AND t2.tag_id = 4
  )
  AND EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM product_tag_mapping AS t2
    WHERE t2.product_id = t.product_id
      AND t2.tag_id = 29
  )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One shortcut way would be using the conditional sum in the having clause as

```
select 
product_id from product_tag_mapping 
group by product_id 
having 
( sum(tag_id=4)= 1 and sum(tag_id=19)=1 ) 
or ( sum(tag_id=4)= 1 and sum(tag_id=29)=1 ) 
or ( sum(tag_id=4)= 1 and sum(tag_id=20)=1 ) ;
```

If there are multiple occurrence of same `tag_id` for a product you may use `>= 1` instead of `=1`

Comment: It seems it's working. Above query gives me proper result for multiple occurrence of same tag_id with =1. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id SEPARATOR ',') AS tag_list
FROM product_tag_mapping GROUP BY product_id HAVING (
FIND_IN_SET( 4, tag_list ) AND FIND_IN_SET( 19, tag_list ))
OR (FIND_IN_SET( 4, tag_list ) AND FIND_IN_SET( 20, tag_list ))
OR (FIND_IN_SET( 4, tag_list ) AND FIND_IN_SET( 29, tag_list ))
```